# How to accurately measure cpu time of a function that returns values in python 3.7?

Tags: python, timer, cpu, benchmarking, timeit

I am trying to measure cpu time of a small function that usually takes about 1500 microseconds. I sometimesget inaccurate or wide confidence interval. I would like to find best accurate way to benchmark the function in python 3.7. I would like to measure the function time + get the return values for other calculations.

I tried defualt_timer from timeit, see my code below.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
times=[] # store the times for 100 runs,then get min,max,averages etc

for i in range (100):
    t1= timer()
    x,y,z = apply_message(s,text)
    t2= timer()
    execution_time= (t2-t1) * 1000000 # convert it to microsecond
    times+=[execution_time]
```

I found sometimes the minimum 1300 and max 75000, big difference. In other cases they are close. What i want to see at least results that gives me 95 confidence interval less than 10% from average.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to get outliers if (for example) your process gets migrated to another CPU during execution.  (So all memory accesses miss in cache for a while, because things were hot in L1d and L2 on the previous core).  This can happen in real life, too.

So you have to decide what you want to measure: the "normal" nothing-weird-happened case, or the full distribution including the worst possible case.

It's definitely *not* a Gaussian normal distribution if you keep the outliers, so take any statistics with a grain of salt if they're based on that assumption!

If you want to exclude outliers, pin the CPU frequency, and pin your process to a single core.  But you can still get outliers when an interrupt handler or other kernel task does any significant amount of work on that core, or a page fault or whatever.

Or on a CPU with Hyperthreading, if another thread runs on the sibling logical core that shares the same physical core.  Or another task on the same machine competes for shared resources like memory bandwidth or cache footprint, or disk I/O.

If you know enough about what your function does and how Python runs it that you can be reasonably certain that the outliers aren't "real", i.e. that your process didn't have the CPU for most of that wall-clock time, or a CPU migration happened, then you can just discard outliers above some threshold.

**Or look at the median time instead of mean.**  Median is not sensitive to huge outliers, but will still respond to variation.

If you're timing with the same input repeatedly so you expect the function to take the same time, you can take the minimum.  (Usually essentially equal to the median.)

Comment: thanks Peter, it seems the min is usually accurate e.g., if i run my function 100 or 1000 times (but not the average). What i know in academia they usually take average and confidence interval, so not sure about taking min?. Also, do you think my approach of timing in python is good enough and do not need to be changed?

Comment: @MWH: Can you give an example from academia where you've seen people report microbenchmark results from something running on an actual CPU?  But anyway, you didn't say anything about wanting to *publish* your results or claim they're meaningful in any context outside of the microbenchmark.  (e.g. as part of a larger program when branch prediction might not be trained for this function before it even starts executing, and when caches might not be hot.  Although 1.5ms is millions of clock cycles, so branch prediction warmup should be minor.)

Comment: @MWH: As far as whether it's a good approach, usually people use `timeit`'s benchmarking functionality to time their function, instead of writing their own repeat loop.  If you were instrumenting calls to this function as part of your full program that might make sense.  If you wanted to publish your results with a confidence interval or something, you'd need to create a truly idle system to benchmark on, and ideally learn about dynamic CPU frequency effects, and all kinds of stuff.  If you just want to know which version of a function is faster for engineering purposes, that's simpler.